# How to delay all queries for a specified timespan?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to delay all the queries I receive in my test database for a specified amount of time. My intent in doing this is to test the "loading" feature in my program. I do not want to alter my queries though! WAITFOR doesn't work for me. If possible, the ideal would be to delay all the queries of a specific connection.

Summarizing: I'd like to delay all the queries of my database via some kind of configuration.

How to do that in SQL Server?

Comment: [WAITFOR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? Unclear what your *real* intention is here.

Comment: Where do your queries originate - a single application (e.g. a website), multiple applications (e.g. desktop clients), SQL command lines?

Comment: I do not want to alter my queries. I'd like to configure the database to delay the queries it receives.

Comment: The queries originate from a C# desktop application.

Comment: There's no option in SQL Server for this -- why would there be? There's no practical application for this in production code. If your code needs this, your code will need to implement it. You can do this without altering queries by introducing a layer for database code and wrapping every execution. That may be a bit of work, but TANSTAAFL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this is not an out-of-the-box feature.

Most people who want to test their data access code write specific test cases to do that. Again, there are lots of different scenarios; the closest to what you describe would be to [capture all the requests going to your server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40960/logging-queries-and-other-t-sql), and then write a harness to replay those queries under test conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really needed? And is there a way to put a delay on the code level? I mean do something like this before the database request.

```
Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
```

Comment: I mean, yes, but I'd have to spread this around my code base and this is not a very clean way to do it. I'd rather have something configured in a specific DB connection, for example.